# How to display searched rows in messagebox

Tags: c#, messagebox

can you please help me on displaying the searched row in message box?

I've below code for searching a value in the row.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // Code to search the  alphanumneric Part Number (in Column1 header called "Name") and highlihgt the row

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells["Age"].Value.ToString().Equals(textBox3.Text.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))   
        {  
            dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the row do you want to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is display the `Name` column's value in a `MessageBox` then do the following:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code to search the  alphanumneric Part Number (in Column1 header called "Name") and highlihgt the row

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells["Age"].Value.ToString().Equals(textBox3.Text.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))   
        {  
            dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Selected = true;
            MessageBox.Show(row.Cells["name"].Value.ToString());
            break;  //This exits the `foreach` loop - not necessary just an assumption.
        }
        else
        {
            //Do something if you don't find what you wanted or `continue` if you want the loop to keep going.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the value of a cell can be `null`. That could throw a `NullReferenceException` at the call to `ToString()`.

Comment: Actually (and i will test this when i get in front of my IDE because i could be totally wrong), I believe a `DBNull.Value` in the cell will return a `String.Empty` value when called.

Comment: The [`Selected` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.selected.aspx) of a `DataGridViewRow` is not read only. That line wouldn't be a problem for compiling. BTW +1 for being so dilligent (editing the question, editing your answer, and giving a code example matching what the OP wants).

Comment: Hi Evan, the code you gave is working, it is showing the value of particular column cell. But I need the entire row in Message box. Can you help on this?

Comment: @Renan Thanks!  Looks like I wont be able to test my `DBNull.Value` theory until tomorrow... BUT! You can bet I will ;)

Comment: @Pravii a `MessageBox` would not be the ideal control for displaying an entire row of data...  You already have a control for that with `DataGridView`.

Comment: @Pravii just as you got the value of a cell, you could get the values for all of them and append them all into a single `string`. Then you show that.

Comment: Hi Renan, I'm not getting all values in the messagebox, it is giving only particular column value when changing the column name.

Comment: @Evan, the requirement is something like finding the value from thousends of rows in gridview and showing into the message box with entire details (like name, age, addres etc.) and the above code is showing the value single time, if the same value is existed some where it's not showing.

Comment: Evan, it showing the same value in dgv if avialbe somewhere else when i removed the break; from the code.
but you know, i need the code for showing the entire row in the messagebox. Plz help me.

Comment: Evan, problem got solved. I got all row value in messagebox. thanks for your help. I appreciate.

Comment: @Pravii no problem.  Sorry I didn't have a chance to write and example of placing the entire row in the box.  If you don't mind, please mark this as the answer by clicking the checkmark below the up/down vote buttons.

Comment: Hi Evan, one more help plz, how to search any part of the name in datagridview? for eg. RamGopalVarma, if i type only varma in search option it should find in gridview. thank you advance.

Comment: @Pravii change `Equals` to `Contains`

Comment: @Pravii  Kind of weird that you un-checked my answer.  If you are getting errors, you should post the error message.

Comment: Hi Evan, I already checked it but not sure why it is unchecked. Any wayz I checked again.

Answer (score 2):

The following:

```
MessageBox.Show("foo")
```

Will display a message box with the text `foo` in a Windows form application (which I suppose is what you have there).

You can learn more about the method and its overloads [on this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx).

Get the information you want in a `string` and happy coding.